# three.js направление осей при наложении текстур

Tags: opengl, three.js

Прошу не бить палками, впервые работаю с 3D. Проблема в следующем. Вот земля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При наложении текстуры, она наложилась таким образом, что полюса проходят по оси Y. Как сделать так, чтобы при наложении полюса находились на оси Z?

Вот код создания земли и наложения текстур:

```
 var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                                                   map: textureLoader.load(mapTexture),
                                                   bumpMap: textureLoader.load(bumpTexture),
                                                   bumpScale: bumpMapScale

                                               });

    if (specularTexture) {
        material.specularMap = textureLoader.load(specularTexture);
        material.specular = new THREE.Color('grey');
        material.shininess = 50.0;
    } else {
        material.shininess = 1.0;
    }
    var commonGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 64, 64));
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(commonGeometry, material);
    mesh.scale.set(radius, radius, radius);

    return mesh;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно повернуть геометрию сферы на 90 градусов против часовой стрелки вокруг оси X:

```
var commonGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 64, 64);
commonGeometry.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/3uLn7t37/) пример r84